# How to perform a query in Spring Data /JPA with a foreign Key?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jpa, spring-data

I have a problem where I need to perform a query using a foreign key in the table. The problem is that in the @Query above(made in the ExpenseRepository above) my logs say that is he's not searching by user id(foreign key) but instead he is searching for the primary key of the expense entity class.

This is my User Entity class:

```
@Entity
public class User implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String email;

    @NotBlank(message = "Password required")
    @Size(min = 6)
    private String password;

    //getters and setters
```

This is my Expenses Entity class:

```
@Entity
public class Expenses implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private long limitValue;
    private long spentValue;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id")
    private User user;

    //getters and setters here
```

Finally this is my repository where I do the query itself

```
public interface ExpensesRepository extends JpaRepository< Expenses, Long> {


    @Query("FROM Expenses g where g.id = :userId")
    GestaoGastos findAllByCurrentUser(@Param("userId") Long userId);

}
```

Comment: JPQL starts with `SELECT {alias}`. Also you cannot share some "id" column between PK and "user" field (particularly as both are auto-generated).

Comment: Yes, but I want to query a user by the userId in order to get only the information that belongs to the loggedIn User. So I need to to this query, do you have any idea on how to solve this. If plz can you show me in code what yoiu are talking about? Regarding the SELECT{alias} it is not mandatory to use it, spring data recognizes it as a select with only a FROM statement :)

Comment: It is MANDATORY to use "SELECT {alias}"; go read the JPA spec if not prepared to take my word - bastardise the JPA spec if you wish and be non-portable. `g.id` in your query is `Expenses.id` which is the "id" column of Expenses ... the PK. And as  said, you cannot share that column with some relation that maps to some auto-generated field in a different class.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use fields, not columns in `@Query`

```
public interface ExpensesRepository extends JpaRepository< Expenses, Long> {
    @Query("FROM Expenses g where g.user.id = :userId")
    GestaoGastos findAllByCurrentUser(@Param("userId") Long userId);
}
```

Comment: Yes that was the problem. I assume that was the problem to. Thank you for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add a method in your repository class like this:

```
public interface ExpensesRepository extends JpaRepository< Expenses, Long> {
    GestaoGastos findAllByUserId(Long userId);
}
```

Comment: It also does the job, but the problem is, it generates unnecessary ‘left outer join’ even though the userId is present in the expense table.